# Type-hinting an overloaded function when parameter default is determined by module level variable

Tags: python, overloading, python-typing

I have a Python function with an input parameter, the value of which controls the type of the return value. The parameter may be omitted (default value `None`), in which case a module level variable is used. This way, the default behavior can be changed by changing the module level variable.
A minimal example:

```py
from typing import overload, Union, Literal, Optional

option_default: Literal["str", "int"] = "int"


@overload
def test(option: Literal["str"]) -> str:
    ...


@overload
def test(option: Literal["int"]) -> int:
    ...


@overload
def test(option: Literal[None] = None) -> Union[str, int]:
    ...


def test(option: Optional[Literal["str", "int"]] = None) -> Union[str, int]:

    if option is None:
        option = option_default

    if option == "str":
        return "foo"
    else:
        return 1


foo: int = test() # Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[str, int]", variable has type "int")

option_default = "str"
baz: str = test() # Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[str, int]", variable has type "str")
```

Normally one would use `typing.overload` to deal with this sort of situation. However, for `test()` without arguments that doesn't work--hence the mypy errors. Is there a better way to provide type info here?

Comment: Controlling how a function like this with a global variable is IMO probably a bad idea (See [Why is global state so evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)). Why do you want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. There is [a proposal on GitHub](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/769) to add `typeof` from TypeScript, but that's a different thing - it doesn't track mutable variables like you've shown.

I don't think such a feature can be implemented, even in theory. It brings a lot of new complexity into type checking. I can think of some problematic scenarios:

1. Passing a callback

```py
def foo(callback: Callable[[], int]):
    some_module.definitely_returns_an_int = callback

option_default = "int"
foo(test)  # ok?
option_default = "str"
```

Now `foo` has saved a function that returns a string.

2. Tracking mutations that happen inside functions

```py
def ints_are_the_bomb():
    global option_default
    option_default = "int"

option_default = "str"
some_other_module.baz()

value = test()
```

Can you be sure about the type of `value`? There's no guarantee that `some_other_module.baz()` didn't call `your_module.ints_are_the_bomb()`. So now you need to track all changes that can ever happen to `your_module.option_default`, potentially across modules. And if client code (if this is a library) can change the flag, then it's just impossible.

To generalize, the type of a value (including functions) can't change when you mutate something. That could break distant code that also happens to have a reference to this object.

Comment: Thanks. I see that supporting these kind of situations in type-checking would open up a can of worms. I guess I was hoping that it would be possible to specify the subtype returned by `test()` (i.e. `str` or `int`) on the call to that function. But on further consideration I agree that allowing the behavior of a function to be changed in this way is a bad idea.